# Unable to complete upgrade from Ubuntu 20.01LTS to 20.04

Tags: boot

Been running Ubuntu 20.04LTS and really happy with it. Running my dual boot desktop after moving home all has been well. I powered on today and got invite to upgrade which I decided to do. My usual diligence did not go far enough I don't think and need urgent help! It appeared to go perfectly well until prompted to reboot to complete the process. I did this and entered my password to enable shut down but it got rejected, and yes it was entered correctly. I was unable to do anything over the next hour or so, and decided that apart from leaving the machine on until I could get a horrid laptop going to seek help,I decided to power off in the naiive hope that it would work .Obviously it has not worked!
Any help will be much appreciated.
I cant upload an image taken of the screen directly as it is too large, but the last line reads as follows: ---[end kernal panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]
I can still access 20.04 LTS as a seperate boot option but it is opening what appears to be a virgin copy on (on  /dev/sda5)There is an advanced option for ubuntu.
I am sure that a routine backup was done before this happened on a seperate external drive.
Help!
Thanks in advance (If there is a way to send a mobile phone camera image then pls let me know)

Comment: there is no 20.01LTS.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Powering off indeed may have done quite some damage.

At first, I would try a reinstall *without formatting the partitions*. This will re-write the system files, but leave your user files and configuration intact. To do this kind of install, select "Something else" in the installer, assign the partitions manually, and make sure the checkbox "Format" is *not* checked.

If that does not work, you will need to revert to a fresh, new install. The benefit there is that you start with a clean system as tested by the developers, old and perhaps obsolete configuration is left out, and you can then can configure and restore your data.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your response. What I meant to say was that I was intending to upgrade from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. My desktop has Windows on one HD and Ubuntu on another. Windows is not used often but is kept for a couple of archive items. Basically it is the usual dual boot system, if left it goes into Ubuntu, no problem. I guess I will have to unplug the HD with Windows, and try your suggestion.